# Should the hubble-telescope and hst tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, merge-request

Should [hubble-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hubble-telescope) and [hst](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hst) be merged?

It looks like I may be the culprit here, I only see three hst questions and they're all mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple enough request, so I've gone ahead and performed the merge; I can't think of a reason not to. In the process, I also created a synonym mapping [hst](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hst) to [hubble-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hubble-telescope). If we see something like [hubble-space-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hubble-space-telescope) arise, I can merge that, if need be. But for now it looks like we're all good.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy and thorough attention!